# How to find all covers and minimal covers?

Tags: integer-programming

Consider a constraint of type
$$c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\cdots+c_nx_n\leq C$$
with $x_i$ binary.

We call a *cover* a subset of the $n$ indices such that the sum of the corresponding coefficients is higher than the right-hand-side $C$.
A cover is *minimal* if, by removing an index of the cover, it is not a cover anymore.

Question: what is a general procedure for finding all covers and all minimal covers?

Comment: For what reason do you want to know them? The covers can simply be enumerated by chosing a subset of the elements and verfiying that the weights are larger than the right-hand-side, but this no practical procedure since there are exponentiel many covers in general.

Comment: I don't have an answer for a non-enumeration based methods for finding all covers or all minimal covers. But if you just need to find one minimal cover that violated by a LP relaxed solution or prove that none such minimal cover exists, then there are some fast heuristics for that.